# How to generalise the parameters with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is my code :

```
const search:Object<T> = (value:Object<T>) => {
    return value.name;
}


const v1 = {name:'name1', age:12}
const v2 = {name:'name2', city:'chennai'}
const v3 = {name:'name3', village:'Madukarai'}

const getSearch1 = search<Object>(v1);
const getSearch2 = search<Object>(v2);
const getSearch3 = search<Object>(v3);
```

[Typescript play ground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmBDATsAFgLgPICMBW8wUAPACoB8MAvDABQBuiANgK7zb6EkUCU1lAbwCwAKBjiYyeFBbIwMRq3gA6MIgC28ANyiAvqIMjQkWPQCM1GALWaMAchvwzdgDQxEAc3ZmATPqPg0Ao%20ltYa7A7hPq4wwACWUACe9ujwYGpxdv7GQfQAzKGO9o55MfRxTEyeEQCyiAAmLADWKIiZ-qI5sF5QAMpIqGgWNAgo6MS4BETkDGY8OgEmMD39Y2ghIwPjk1wz9D7znYHd0quDBZtrE5zTDHnzQA)

I would like to understand my `search` function to accept the object or array ( at present object ) to consider it's param as a type. how to do it?

I am getting an error as :

```
Type 'Object' is not generic.(2315)
```

Comment: The code only shows what you'd do with an object - what if it's an array? (`return value.name` wouldn't make sense)

Comment: I need the answer for object. from it will take the idea. please check `( at present object ) `

Comment: Your current code isn't really valid. Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG4YMw) what you're looking for instead?   If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I  missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz -what is `N` stands for here. Both `N` and `,` is new for me. can you please add your answer with details please?

Comment: `N` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter corresponding to the type of value at the `name` property of the argument.  So the return value of `search()` is of type `N`.  I will add the answer *if* it the code meets your needs.  Does it?

Comment: Yes please. as well please explain how my code is not valid.